# background-color stays white

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website but for some reason my `background-color` is not working. Nothing happens, the `background-color` just stays white.

The code that is not working is below :

```
.sub-header {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

My complete code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7mdqaop/ and the interesting lines are 158, 159, 160.

Comment: `.sub-header` has a zero height because you are floating its children. And what does this have to do with `margin-top`?

Comment: Your title and question seems different.

Comment: Turnip i put margin top by mistake

Comment: @ShreyasSreenivasa Then change title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand it correctly you are trying to do [image: screenshot]:

**HTML**

```
<header class="sub-header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="main-navbar-heading-2">Chezzles</a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw bars" style="font-size:24px"></i>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.sub-header {
        background-color: black !important;
    }
    .sub-header .dropdown {
        background-color: black !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .sub-header .dropdown * {
      color: white;
    }
    .sub-header .dropdown i {
      top: 15px;
    }

    .main-navbar-heading-2 {
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-family: Raleway;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
```

like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/j7mdqaop/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's because all elements in your `.sub-header` are not in the flow (because of absolute position)

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7mdqaop/3/)

```
.sub-header {
    background-color: black !important;
    display: block;
}

.main-navbar-heading-2 {
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

**Note** : I add `display: block;` to make the `background-color` property occupy all the line instead of just the title "Chezzles" but you can keep `inline` if you wants.